# LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@141084504' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

When using getX and Flutter I get following error:

LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@141084504' has not been initialized

This is the code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:auth/view/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Get.to(() => SignUPScreen());
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircleAvatar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can provide source code signup_screen.dart?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to navigate to another screen and having an issue on the timer. What I would suggest is to convert your StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget and putting the timer inside the `initState()`.

Here's the code:

```
void initState() {
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Get.to(() => SignUPScreen());
  });
  super.initState();
}
```